# How to make focus area smaller when using SwiftOCR?

Tags: ios, swift, ocr

I'm currently working with [SwiftOCR](https://github.com/garnele007/SwiftOCR) and trying to reduce the areas where the camera has focus. The reason is to be able to register for example a receipt, such as receipt number, date and amount. But i want to register one at a time.

Like the picture below.

[image]

The idea is that the text will automatically be fed into the correct text field and then be able to register a new one directly.